# Laravel Flash Data in View with Joins

Tags: laravel

I feel bad for asking this question and may receive down votes.  But my mind is fried...

I am trying to access flash data in my view.  The flash data is an array from a query that has joined data.

Usually I can just access in the view like `$Flashdata->columnname;`

But with the joined data it doesn't seem to work that way.

Can someone please educate me

**Controller**

```
$advertisements = Advertisement::join('categories', 'advertisements.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                                        ->join('users', 'advertisements.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                        ->select('advertisements.id', 'advertisements.approved', 'users.email', 'categories.category', 'advertisements.title', 'advertisements.phone', 'advertisements.created_at');

$advertisements->remember(5)->get();

return View::make('admin.dashboard')->with('ads', $advertisements);
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($ads as $ad) 
    <tr>
        <td>{{$ad->title}}</td>        <-- Not working
        <td>{{$ad->category_id}}</td>  <-- Not working
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually are not passing the results of the query to your view!

Try this ;)

```
$advertisements = $advertisements->remember(5)->get();
```